# MS Charting controls

Tags: mschart

Beginning to use MS Charting controls in our website. Are they good to work with?
Are there any pitfalls to watch out for?  Any other better charting controls you guys have some across

Answer (score 0):

Charting seems to be moving towards front end and javascript - this has a bonus that they are mostly free. Check out gRaphael, Flot, extjs before making a final decision.

Answer (score 0):

Google also has a good [charting api](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/) that you might want to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MS didn't develop those charting controls, they were bought off [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com) quite recently and included as a plugin for .NET.  .NET 4 will include MS charting controls natively.